# Is it possible to efficiently get all the polygons inside a polygon from a shapefile without using PostGIS?

Tags: shapefile, polygon

I have a huge shapefile (over 400MB) of an entire city that contains many polygons of the residential area of this city. I can check it on QGIS as the following:

[image]

This shapefile contains a huge number of polygons, and I'd like cut a small shapefile from it in a circular or squared area around a point. So, let's say I give a point to a system, I want to return all the polygons around this area inside an offset (just so I can send only this segmentation of the data to the frontend of my application).

I know I could convert this shapefile to GeoJSON and find what are the polygons that exist inside the area that I have created (using turf.js for example), but that would be a brute force solution and it wouldn't be efficient.

On the other hand, I know I could install PostgreSQL and PostGIS and implement solutions like [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197409/finding-all-polygons-inside-of-a-polygon).

My doubt is that if I can achieve the goal of finding all polygons inside a polygon efficiently using only the command line, Python or JavaScript without implementing a spatial index for that, working directly with the shapefile. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this using `ogr2ogr` with

```bsh
# SHP from Natural Earth Data
ogr2ogr out.shp ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp -dialect SQLite -sql "SELECT * FROM ne_110m_admin_0_countries WHERE ST_intersects(ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT (1 43)', 4326), 10), ne_110m_admin_0_countries.geometry);"
```

To sort out execution with index, you may want to add after `ogr2ogr` the option `--debug ON`

PS: the buffer units are degrees here because using EPSG 4326 units. The points coordinates are longitude 1 and latitude 43. You may need to reproject if you want to use meters or directly use a layer that use a projection based on meters.

Comment: Using the `time` command... I've realized that the time it takes for doing this operation is the same with the index file `.qix` generated or not (6 seconds in my case).  So, creating the spatial index is necessary in this case? Is it used automatically?

Comment: It seems here the index is not used as when using SQLite dialect, can't use the shp index according to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153472/using-a-shapefile-spatial-index-with-ogr2ogr-and-ogr-datasource-executesql

Comment: Made an edit. Not sure it's faster (small dataset on my test so not sure if major speed difference)

Comment: If you want to try directly with my dataset it's [this one](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19qFklmA-_KHhUjmLvyBJ-NIhPJC0h0r9/view?usp=sharing). I've been testing these two lines here. The second one is actually slower, it takes around 20 seconds while the first takes 6 seconds on my computer. However, when I use the `debug` mode I see that the index is being created as you said. I think the problem is that it's creating the index on the run instead of using the `.qix` that we've created.

Comment: So, in theory, if there's a way of creating the index before executing the second command and using it instead of creating it on the run... it could make it faster.

Comment: What is your projection? No prj in your link

Comment: Tested with GPKG (without using SHP as an intermediate) and a spatial index. Take 4 s. Not sure if I miss something. Done comparison with PostGIS 120ms with a spatial index Tested on the same machine...

Comment: Well, in case performance becomes an issue I'll use the PostGIS solution since the query of your second sample with an index is so much faster... All questions here that I find and the documentation don't seem to give any extra procedure besides creating the `.qix` index file with the command `ogrinfo`...

Comment: Quite annoying. Does not seem to be able to use the spatial index correctly using only GPKG...

Comment: Unhappy because at the end, partial answer with gaps in reasoning. Removed SHP index creation part of the recipe as qix can't be used with SQLite dialect